# Can't access vector size

Tags: c++, vector

```
        #include <vector>
        using namespace std;
        int main(){
        vector<double> one;

        one.size;
        return 0;
    }
```

.

```
 error C3867: 'std::vector<_Ty>::size': function call missing argument list; use '&std::vector<_Ty>::size' to create a pointer to member
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::vector<double>
1>          ]
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012. Any ideas what is causing those errors?

Comment: `size` is a member function, not a data member – `one.size();`.

Comment: size is a function.  Add ().  As in "function call missing argument list".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

std::vector has no size member but it has size() member function.
you need to change `one.size;` to `one.size();`

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just used the visual studios auto complete feature, which gave me one.size instead of .size(); :/